# How to obtain an array of subclasses in Rails

Tags: ruby, reflection, inheritance, metaprogramming, inspect

I have a model object which subclasses ActiveRecord. Additionally, using STI, I have defined subclasses of this object, which define different types and behaviors. The structure looks something like this:

```
class AppModule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app 
end

class AppModuleList < AppModule

end

class AppModuleSearch < AppModule

end

class AppModuleThumbs < AppModule

end
```

Now, in a view where the user has the option to create new AppModules, I would like them to select from a dropdown menu. However I have not been able to get a list of subclasses of AppModule using the subclasses() method:

```
<% form_for(@app_module) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :type %><br />
    <%= f.select(:type, options_from_collection_for_select(@app_module.subclasses().map{ |c| c.to_s }.sort)) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `subclasses' for #<AppModule:0x1036b76d8>
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which version of Ruby on Rails are you using?

Comment: Class has a `descendents` method in [3.0.0](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/Class#descendants-instance_method), but not [2.3.8](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/Class#descendants-instance_method).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks as though [`subclasses`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-subclasses) and the like is a [recent addition](https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/subclasses.rb) (the method exists on various classes at various points in time, but kept getting shuffled around and removed; that link seems to be the earliest point that the method stuck around). If upgrading to the most recent version of RoR isn't an option, you can write your own `subclasses` and populate it using [`Class#inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Class.html#M002785) (which is what RoR's [`descendents_tracker`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb) does).

Comment: For anyone directed here by Google, if your classes are lazy loaded, DescendantsTracker won't know about them until they are used.

Answer (score 5):

`AppModule.descendants.map &:name` is what you're looking for.  As in:

```
<% form_for(@app_module) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :type %><br />
    <%= f.select(:type, options_from_collection_for_select(AppModule.descendants.map(&:name).sort)) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```